# Visual Studio 2019: Exception thrown: read access violation. **argv** was 0x2

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, argv

I'm trying to pass command-line arguments into my program. I have it set in the properties menu.

When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(const char *argv[], int argc) {
    printf("%s", *argv);
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> Exception thrown: read access violation. **argv** was 0x2

I have the debugger set to "Deubg x64" in both settings. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is a bit surprising that the compiler is not generating a warning about the signature for `main()` being incorrect.  GCC would complain about the non-standard signature.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments to `main` aren't in the correct order.  They should be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
```